# what difference have ListActivity between Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-widget, listactivity

I need to change Activity to ListActivity. But I can't start my project... do ı need change manifest.xml for it??

Or how can I change screen from Activity to ListActivity? Is there any difference to `startActivity(new Intent(this, list.class))` ?

```
10-05 17:34:54.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11550): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{spexco.hus.cepvizyon/spexco.hus.cepvizyon.CepVizyon}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
10-05 17:34:54.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11550):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
10-05 17:34:54.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11550):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
10-05 17:34:54.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11550):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
10-05 17:34:54.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11550):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
10-05 17:34:54.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11550):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-05 17:34:54.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11550):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-05 17:34:54.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11550):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
10-05 17:34:54.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11550):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-05 17:34:54.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11550):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-05 17:34:54.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11550):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
10-05 17:34:54.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11550):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
10-05 17:34:54.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11550):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-05 17:34:54.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11550): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
10-05 17:34:54.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11550):     at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:236)
10-05 17:34:54.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11550):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:201)
10-05 17:34:54.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11550):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1622)
10-05 17:34:54.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11550):     at spexco.hus.cepvizyon.CepVizyon.onCreate(CepVizyon.java:21)
10-05 17:34:54.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11550):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-05 17:34:54.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11550):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
10-05 17:34:54.722: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11550):     ... 11 more
10-05 17:34:55.432: ERROR/PowerManagerService(129): setPowerState SystemProperties.get siBefornormal
10-05 17:35:01.872: ERROR/PowerManagerService(129): setPowerState SystemProperties.get siBefornormal




     public class CepVizyon extends ListActivity  {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,   
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 
        ListView list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        ImageButton b1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.menu_mycameras);
        ImageButton b2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.menu_aboutus);
        ImageButton b3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.menu_help);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(CepVizyon.this, CameraSelectScreen.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(CepVizyon.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        b3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            }
        });
    }
}
```

this is my class..

And This is my main.xml    I dont use list there, ı put ıt for error stack. but nothıng change.

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_weight="3">

<ImageButton android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/menu_mycameras"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_cameras">
</ImageButton>
<ListView android:id="@+id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" ></ListView>
<ImageButton 
    android:paddingTop="20px"
    android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/menu_aboutus"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_aboutus">
</ImageButton>

<ImageButton android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/menu_help"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_help">
</ImageButton>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace/error you got in your LogCat?

Comment: It would help if you also could post your main.xml layout file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ID of your ListView must be: "@android:id/list". This way the ListActivity will find it.

Answer (score 1):

Try reading stack traces. It tells you exactly what you need: "Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'"

Comment: benvd I think you are right but there is no need for being rude

Comment: How is that rude? I was simply stating facts. Should I sugercoat my words in smileys or what?